# Why is is center_x: 35 so far left and outside its parent container?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

[image]

```
MDScreen:
    name: "main"
    md_bg_color: rgba(246, 250, 255, 255)
    MDFloatLayout:
        RunStopCard:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .875}
            md_bg_color: 1, 1, 0, 1
            radius: 20
            size_hint: .85, .23
            MDLabel:
                text: "STOP"
                font_size: "36sp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .35,"center_y": .5}
                color: rgba(71, 92, 119, 255)
            MDLabel:
                text: "RUN"
                font_size: "36sp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .75,"center_y": .5}
                color: rgba(71, 92, 119, 255)
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying you question? It's hard to know what exactly you're having problems with. Also, we would greatly appreciate it if you could format you code properly - you can do this by surounding the code with three backticks - ```

Comment: Please include your definition of the `RunStopCard` class.